# Generic function holder in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, generics, typedef

So I know how to use `typedef` in C++

But if I want to have a generic function array can I do it?

For example:

```
foo() { cout << "hello world" << endl; }


foo2(int a) { cout << "hello friend number " << a << endl; }


var_type[] function_holder = { foo, foo2 }

function_holder[0]();
function_holder[1](1);
```

Comment: You could make an array of function pointers to the same types of functions, but you can't put a function by value into an array.

Comment: `std::any` or `std::variant` might help

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
std::function<void()> functions[] = { 
   foo, 
   std::bind( foo2, 1 )
};

for( auto f : functions ) f();
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/VPbxRs)